# A version of "Riddick" (2013) with opening and final scene cut off, is it official?

Tags: alternate-version, riddick

Yesterday I watched [Riddick (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411250/) movie with:

- initial scene of approx. 20-30 minutes (when Riddick becomes the Lord Marshal) narrowed to only 2-3 minutes cameo / reference, as Riddick lies on desert and recalls that events,
- [final scene](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/238467/7885) cut off.

Movie ends "in-air", with split with Johns and wording:

> I'll tell you this, Johns. Sooner or later, we all have to head home.
>
> Tell Dahl to keep it warm for me.
>
> And, Johns, you keep a strong spine.

Is this shorter version anywhere official? Or is this just some invention of my local TV station?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddick_(film)#Differences_in_plot_from_theatrical_release which points to (among other sites) https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=661847

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. So, I am voting to close my own question since answer to it can be found in the Internet, by a simple Google / Wikipedia search query.

Comment: @trejder That's not really a valid reason for closing the question, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Lack of minimal research used to be a reason, either here or maybe on StackOverflow, and could probably be a legitimate write-in reason.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It never really was a valid close-reason here. I don't know about SO. It can very well be a downvote reason, but we've never really been closing questions for it unless they ran foul of other problems. At least over the last few years I can remember.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thanks for clearing this up. It is a clear close-reason on other sites at SE and I assumed it is here as well. I have voted to close this question, but it remained open -- I believe other agreed with you. That's just fine with me! :> Since we decided to keep this one open, in now would be good to have an answer here. Should I write myself, by copying above comment and linking mentioned Wiki article, if no one else is going to write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [BCdotWEB in a comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111407/a-version-of-riddick-2013-with-opening-and-final-scene-cut-off-is-it-offici#comment190358_111407) the shorter version is an official theatrical version while the longer one is director's cut version of the movie.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddick_(film)#Differences_in_plot_from_theatrical_release):

> A number of additions to the plot are included in the director's cut of the movie which was released on Blu-ray and DVD on January 14, 2014 and provided a longer story than the theatrical version. The extended cut of the movie is approximately 8 minutes and 9 seconds longer than the theatrical version and includes extended and additional scenes not seen in the theatrical version.
>
> In the extended version, there is an additional scene which takes place aboard the Necromonger capital ship where Riddick kills Krone and finds out that Vaako has crossed the threshold into the Underverse, seen as a large hole in space surrounded by gas. Riddick looks out the window as he is told that Vaako has gone to achieve transcendence, where he is both dead and alive.

Sources: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddick_(film)#Differences_in_plot_from_theatrical_release), [Movie-Censorship.com](https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=661847) and [BCdotWEB's comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111407/a-version-of-riddick-2013-with-opening-and-final-scene-cut-off-is-it-offici#comment190358_111407).